# Clustering of medical procedures from claims data

Tags: clustering

Imagine quite extensive medical claims dataset, containing patient related claims with medical diagnosis and procedure. While the diagnoses are neatly classified according to IDC, the procedures are not classified at all. So you end with about 8000 different procedures, with some being very similar. (For example several procedures for blood test)
The current state is quite unusable, for most applications we would need to cluster related procedures.
I tried clustering based on linguistic similarity of procedures' names, but this didn't yield good results. I also tried to use collaborative filtering, with number of times patient had certain procedure as analogy to movie rating. I didn't have success with this method either, but I have not discarded it completely.

I would like to hear about your ideas how you would tackle this problem, or even if it is possible to find clusters of related procedures by statistical tools.